# yii2 Getting unknown property: DefaultController::pageHeading

Tags: php, yii2

I create a module in yii2 advanced template backend/modules/fansoftware
when I access it gives me the error

> "yii2 Getting unknown property: backend\modules\fansoftware\controllers\DefaultController::pageHeading"

I use the path in the Url as 
localhost/mysite/backend/web/fansoftware/default

```
<?php
     namespace app\modules\fansoftware\controllers;
     use yii\web\Controller;
     /** * Default controller for the fansoftware` module /
       class DefaultController extends Controller {
     /* * Renders the index view for the module *
    @return string
     */ public function actionIndex() {
     return $this->render('index');
     }
  }
```

Please anyone tell me what is the actual problem?

Comment: Looks like there is no pageHeading property defined on you DefaultController. Can you share your controller code?

Comment: `<?php

namespace app\modules\fansoftware\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * Default controller for the `fansoftware` module
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Renders the index view for the module
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}`